# Finding \ inside a string

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I need to validate a string that it's an actual number.

```
let str = '\n2';
```

But Number(str) returns 2 instead of NaN.

How can I check if the given string contains any backslash?

Comment: This is two separate questions. Which do you want: to know if a string is a number, or if it contains a backslash? (Which this string doesn’t, btw, it contains as escape character.)

Comment: @NullDev `parseInt` is insufficient.

Comment: I just want to check if the given string is the actual number and nothing else is entered in the string. But Number('\n2') returns a number instead of NaN. Is there any other way to check this?

Comment: The question has already been answered.

Comment: if the main intention is to check the number against white-space characters, `/\s/.test(str)` should be enough I think.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` inside a string literal is interpreted as a newline character, and newline characters, like all space characters, are just skipped over when you try to turn the string into a number:

```js
// these are all whitespace characters
console.log(
  Number('   5'),
  Number('\n5'),
  Number('\t5'),
);
```

If you want to extract a number only if the string contains *only* number characters and nothing else, I'd match digits with a regular expression instead:

```js
const extractNum = str => {
  const match = str.match(/^\d+$/);
  return match
    ? Number(match[0])
    : NaN;
};

console.log(
  extractNum('\n5'),
  extractNum('5')
);
```

To permit decimals as well:

```js
const extractNum = str => {
  const match = str.match(/^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/);
  return match
    ? Number(match[0])
    : NaN;
};

console.log(
  extractNum('\n5'),
  extractNum('5'),
  extractNum('0.123'),
  extractNum('.55')
);
```